# react native text input keyboard how to show dot instead of comma?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-textinput

I have an issue in react-native text input ios and I want to show a numeric keyboard. Here is the code that describes very well:

```js
<TextInput
  keyboardType={'numeric'}
  onChangeText={(setCurrentValue) => this.setState({ setCurrentValue })}
/>
```

but in ios shows a comma in the keyboard, as in the picture below:

[image]

Instead of that comma I want to show a dot. Somebody have an idea how to do without replace method in JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that's related to localisation settings of the user. But you could try either *keyboardType*: `decimal-pad` or `numbers-and-punctuation`. Latter one will offer both comma and dot (+ other characters) to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard depend on region
For example if you set your region from General > keyboard > language and region > to "Russia" you will get comma instead of dot.
Set it to US you will get the dot instead of comma